# Fetching documents of sub-collections in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch sub-collection documents from my firestore database.

**Collection Imgs:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**My current code:**

```
const fetchHighlight =async()=>{
      
    const Highlight = []
    const HighlightDbId = await 
 db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk').collection('4C4kd2QnaQhcp9knexkW').get()
       console.log(HighlightDbId)
    }
    React.useEffect(()=>
    {
      fetchHighlight ()
     
    }, [])
```

Comment: Are you trying to get one specific document (from what's inside the doc) or an array of all the docs in your subcollection?

Comment: currently , I want only to get the first doc's collection id ,`db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk').collection('4C4kd2QnaQhcp9knexkW').get()` I want to get that `4C4kd2QnaQhcp9knexkW`

Comment: You must edit your question accordingly, the edit queue is full so I can't do it for you.

Comment: I think your can edit your answer below ? if not just send a pseudo code here , I will accept your answer in the answers section

Comment: Done, tell me if it works

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to fetch your query at the end of your chain, and the subcollection `4C4kd2QnaQhcp9knexkW` does not exist, it's the id of a document in the subcollection you're trying to access. The right subcollection ID was `hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryETQZnz2`.
To sum up, you could go this way:

```
const yourDocument = (await db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk')
  .collection('hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryETQZnz2').doc('YOUR_DOC_ID').get()).data()
```

or this way:

```
const yourDocument = (await db.collection('highlights/2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk/hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryETQZnz2')
  .doc('YOUR_DOC_ID').get()).data()
```

**Edit**
If you want to fetch only the first document of the subcollection you can go this way:

```
const yourDocument = (await db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk')
  .collection('hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryETQZnz2') // subcollection ref
  .orderBy("createdAt", "asc") // index
  .limit(1) // limit the size of your response
  .get()) // send the request and wait for it (you could also use '.then()' here)
  .docs[0] // get the first doc of the array
  .data() // retrieve the doc's data use `.id` instead if you want its id
```

And if you want to get the first subcollection of a doc you should go this way with the listCollections method:

```
const subcollectionId = (await db
  .doc('highlights/2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk')
  .listCollections())[0] // retrieve the first subcollection `.id`
```

Note that this only [works with](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document) the node.js library, if you're attempting to do your query fore the front-end, it will fail. Then you should simply put a reference of your subcollection inside your parent doc by an update when creating your subcollection in the first place:

```
// const HighlightDbId = creating you subcollection
db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk').update({
  subcollection: HighlightDbId
});
```

And simply retrieve the field `subcollection` when you need to fetch data from its subcollection.

Comment: Yes, you can fetch an entire collection.  It is just a query with no filters.

Comment: I corrected my answer...

Comment: I cannot fetch it if I use this as well

Comment: What consoling `HighlightDbId` gives you?

Comment: it shows this query https://ibb.co/Bq5YmLF m it has no connection to the data of the collection

Comment: @DougStevenson Please take a look at the edited question

Comment: And what's in `docs` here, doesn't it give you an array of the docs of your collection?

Comment: no it's an empty array

Comment: @AlanKersaudy can you please check if I am putting the right doc id and collection id based on the images in the question

Comment: @M.ElYaakoubi as you can see above, I edited my answer, part of the problem was that you used a document ID instead of its parent collection ID, so firestore was looking for a subcollection that did exist. The last version should work fine.

Comment: `hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryETQZnz2` is what I want to get !!

Comment: the subcollection ref

Comment: See if my last update works. Are you using the node.js library or the web v8 one?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem by adding the last doc :

```
 db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk').collection('4C4kd2QnaQhcp9knexkW').doc('XXXXXXXX').get()
```

Comment: This might solve your problem, but it doesn't answer the question you asked, you should either edit the question or ask a new question elsewhere and accept the answer that solved the problem given in your question.

Comment: I appreciate the help nevertheless

Comment: Now you need to edit your answer, for I can un-downvote it.

Comment: @AlanKersaudy please how can I know the collection id of a query , for example : ```db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk').collection('XXXXXXXXXXX').```

Comment: How can I get that XXXXXXX ??

Comment: Update your question first, and accept my answer if it answers the question.

Comment: please help ! I will definitely accept the answer and update it !