# how to fetch subcollection's data in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch a collection' data called highlights that has a doc and another collection ,
I want to retrieve only the data :
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
  const fetchHighlight =async()=>{

    const HighlightDbId =  await db.collection('highlights').doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk')
.collection('hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryeTQZnHz2').get()
    console.log(HighlightDbId)

    }
React.useEffect(()=>
    {
      fetchHighlight ()
     
    }, [])
```

How can I retrieve this collection's data (tag,teamColor, team ...)
This is what I get when i console log :
[image]

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395868/fetching-sub-collection-in-firestore-database)?

Comment: you could have answered the question if you took a look on it  , I fixed it anyways It was missing a doc in the last of the query

Comment: I recommend assuming a positive intent here, because I *did* check that question. The problem is that you fixed the problem in that question, so that the snippets of code are now the same aside from the last string you pass in. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I really appreciate your help sir

Answer (score 1):

There are good hands on examples for all the basic cases such as this one. In your code, you get the snapshot of the collection query right, but you need to iterate docs on in snapshot object.

Look for more in here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection.